How to delegate focus navigation in a sublist of items using react-aria GidList component?
I have a list of menu items, one of those items can have a sublist property to open another menu aside of the main list.
When I use the mouse to navigate, it is working as expected, but when I use the keyboard to navigate to the list item that contains the sublist, an error of focus is triggered.
Here the working example
